# transitive action of G on A.

Tags: group-theory

> Assume  $G \subset S_A$ is abelian and acts transitively on $A$.
>
> 1. Show that $\sigma(a) \ne a$ for any $a \in A$ if $\sigma \ne 1$.
> 2. Deduce $o(G)=o(A)$.

My attempt:

Transitively means, for every $x,y$ of $A$ there is $g \in G$ s.t.  $g\cdot x=y$ so probably by definition first part looks obvious, though second part doesn't.

Comment: What is $S_A$? What is $\sigma(a)$? What is o(G)?

Comment: $S_A$ is all permutations of A. o(G) is order. $\sigma$ is element of $S_A$

Comment: Thank you. The key word in your attempt is probably "probably".

Comment: your question 1. implies 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose $\sigma \in G$ and $\exists a\in A$ such that $\sigma(a) =a$. Then for any $b\in A, \exists \tau \in G$ such that $\tau(a) = b$. Then, since $G$ is abelian,
   $$
   \sigma(b) = \sigma(\tau(a)) = \tau(\sigma(a)) = \tau(a) = b
   $$
   and so $\sigma =1$
2. Fix $a\in A$ and consider the map
   $$
   f : G\to A \text{ given by } \sigma \mapsto \sigma(a)
   $$
   By part (i), $f$ is injective, and it is surjective since $G$ acts transitively. Hence,
   $$
   |G| = |A|
   $$

Comment: your $S$ should be an $A$.